# Evaluation under the derivative

Tags: maxima

I give

```
depends(u,r)$
er : diff(u,r)$
er, u = r^2;
```

I am getting:

                                        `d    2
    (%o47)                              -- (r )
                                        dr`

However, I would like to obtain

```
2 r
```

How can force MAXIMA to evaluate that derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! Use the keyword `nouns`:

```
depends(u,r)$
er : diff(u,r)$
er, nouns, u = r^2;
```